# Getting " failed to unmarshal install-config.yaml' error while trying to build cluster on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openshift

Any help would be appreciated. I've built the config file using Red Hat docs as guidance - but I keep getting this error:

ERROR failed to fetch Metadata: failed to load asset "Install Config": failed to create install config: failed to unmarshal install-config.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field InstallConfig.compute of type []types.MachinePool

The install-config.yaml is below

[screenshot of the install-config.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reYe7.png)

Comment: Please post the code  or error as text in your question, not an image.

Comment: I think you need to check your install config with yamllint.